# How can I rearrange nested codes with php

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

Here is my function which nested same code again and again. I thought there must be a precise and easy way to do it.

```
function altkategoriler($Id)
{

    $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
        array(
            "Pid"=>$Id
        )
    );

    $tumKategoriler = [];

    foreach ($kategoriler as $kategori) {


            $tumKategoriler[] = $kategori->Id;
            $Id= $kategori->Id;
            $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                array(
                    "Pid"=>$Id
                )
            );

            foreach($kategoriler as $kategori){
                $tumKategoriler[] = $kategori->Id;
                $Id= $kategori->Id;
                $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                    array(
                        "Pid"=>$Id
                    )
                );

                foreach($kategoriler as $kategori){
                    $tumKategoriler[] = $kategori->Id;
                    $Id= $kategori->Id;
                    $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                        array(
                            "Pid"=>$Id
                        )
                    );

                    foreach($kategoriler as $kategori){
                        $tumKategoriler[] = $kategori->Id;
                        $Id= $kategori->Id;
                        $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                            array(
                                "Pid"=>$Id
                            )
                        );

                       
                    }
                }


            }
          

    }

    return  $tumKategoriler;

}
```

And the this part of code to get value from database

```
$kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                array(
                    "Pid"=>$Id
                )
            );
```

I want to do something like that?

```
function altkategoriler($Id)
{

    $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
        array(
            "Pid"=>$Id
        )
    );

    $tumKategoriler = [];

    foreach ($kategoriler as $kategori) {


            $tumKategoriler[] = $kategori->Id;
            $Id= $kategori->Id;
            $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                array(
                    "Pid"=>$Id
                )
            );

            foreach($kategoriler as $kategori){
                $tumKategoriler[] = $kategori->Id;
                $Id= $kategori->Id;
                $kategoriler = $this->kategori_model->get_all(
                    array(
                        "Pid"=>$Id
                    )
                );

               altkategoriler($Id);

            }
          

    }

    return  $tumKategoriler;

}
```

Comment: We are here to help you solve issues, Not to refactor your code. You have to put an effort to learn this. For your reference: https://phptherightway.com/

Comment: You may want to consider using a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal) to traverse your hierarchical data, instead of using a recursive function/method in PHP.